# How to test functions inside a React component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I'm having trouble trying to test functions declared inside a React component.
In my case i have these functions called `handleChange` and `changeCapacity` , they're used by the `Form.control` element, it's a Select.

I wrote a test that should use these Selects, so i thought i was also testing the functions they are associated with, but apparently i'm not since my Coverage file state that the functions are not tested.

This is the Component i'm testing,

```
const TableFilter: React.FC<TableFilterProps> = ({ handleTables }) => {
  const tables: TableI[] = useSelector(tablesSelector);

  const filteredTables: TableI[] = useSelector(filteredTablesSelector);

  const prevCapacity: number = useSelector(capacitySelector);
  const prevLocation: string = useSelector(locationSelector);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const locations: string[] = tables.map(
    (table: { location: string }) => table.location
  );
  const capacity: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  const uniqueLocations = [...new Set(locations)];

  const handleChange = (event: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    let locationFilter = event.target.value;

    dispatch(storeLocation(locationFilter));

    if (filteredTables && prevCapacity) {
      const available = tables.filter(
        (table: { location: string; capacity: number }) =>
          table.location === locationFilter && table.capacity >= prevCapacity
      );

      available.length === 0
        ? handleTables()
        : dispatch(filterTables(available));
    } else {
      const filteredArr = tables.filter(
        (table: { location: string }) => table.location === locationFilter
      );
      dispatch(filterTables(filteredArr));
    }
  };

  const changeCapacity = (event: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    let capacityFilter = event.target.value;

    dispatch(storeCapacity(capacityFilter));

    if (filteredTables && prevLocation) {
      const available = tables.filter(
        (table: { capacity: number; location: string }) =>
          table.capacity >= capacityFilter && table.location === prevLocation
      );

      available.length === 0
        ? handleTables()
        : dispatch(filterTables(available));
    } else {
      const filteredArr = tables.filter(
        (table: { capacity: number }) => table.capacity >= capacityFilter
      );
      dispatch(filterTables(filteredArr));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Select a table</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          onChange={handleChange}
          as="select"
          aria-label="form-select-location"
        >
          <option>Select your table's location</option>
          {uniqueLocations &&
            uniqueLocations.map((location: string, index: number) => (
              <option aria-label="location" key={index} value={location}>
                {location}
              </option>
            ))}
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Select the capacity of your table</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          onChange={changeCapacity}
          as="select"
          aria-label="form-select-capacity"
        >
          <option>Number of persons sitting </option>
          {capacity &&
            capacity.map((capacity: number, index: number) => (
              <option aria-label="capacity" key={index} value={capacity}>
                {capacity}
              </option>
            ))}
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default TableFilter;
```

this is the test i'm running on this Component:

```
describe("TableFilter", () => {
  const filteredTablesSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(
    actions,
    "filteredTablesSelector"
  );
  const tablesSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, "tablesSelector");
  const capacitySelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, "capacitySelector");
  const locationSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, "locationSelector");

  beforeEach(() => {
    filteredTablesSelectorSpy.mockReset().mockReturnValue([]);
    tablesSelectorSpy.mockReset().mockReturnValue([]);
    capacitySelectorSpy.mockReset().mockReturnValue(0);
    locationSelectorSpy.mockReset().mockReturnValue("");
  });

  test("testing Capacity and Location Selects, should find the Table with the values selected", () => {
    render(<TableFilter handleTables={() => {}} />);

    const capacitySelect = screen.getByLabelText("form-select-capacity");
    const locationSelect = screen.getByLabelText("form-select-location");

    expect(capacitySelect).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(locationSelect).toBeInTheDocument();

    waitFor(() =>
      user.selectOptions(
        capacitySelect,
        within(capacitySelect).getByRole("option", { name: "8" })
      )
    );

    waitFor(() =>
      user.selectOptions(
        locationSelect,
        within(locationSelect).getByRole("option", { name: "Patio" })
      )
    );

    waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.getByRole("option", { name: "8" })).toBeInTheDocument()
    );

    waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.getByRole("option", { name: "Patio" })).toBeInTheDocument()
    );

    waitFor(() => expect(filteredTablesSelectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));
    waitFor(() => expect(tablesSelectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    waitFor(() => expect(capacitySelectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));
    waitFor(() => expect(locationSelectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));
  });
});
```

Comment: For what it is worth, you appear to be misusing/abusing [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) here-- you are using it as a stand-in for a test-id (which itself should be avoided because you should be using accessible matchers).  You should properly wire up a label to the input using an `id` on the input and a `for` on the label, and then match by that label text.

Comment: Thank you Alexander! I ended up using lots of aria-labels because i was having trouble finding accessible matchers but i'll try to remove themI'd try using the label as you suggested, thanks!

Comment: Are the handler functions not being covered at all, or are they not being fully covered? Surely testing the `<select>` elements would trigger them, but because you have `if` blocks inside, the tests may not be covering both branches.